# SolrNet - How to get search filter options

Tags: solr, solrnet

If I made a search for "TV" I want to have search filters on the sidebar which gives me options like following...

### Brand

Sony (10)

Samsung(5)

Panasonic(3)

When I click on SONY, it will only return Sony tvs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called 'faceting'. Check out [Facets in SolrNet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Facets) and [Solr faceting overview](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview).

Also, the [SolrNet sample app](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/SampleApp) implements facets, you can use it for guidance.

Comment: Thanks again Mauricio, I wonder where would I have been without your help on SolrNet. Your sample app is awesome! I dnt know how to pay you back for the time that you have saved me.